# How to create a matrix of strings as row column and store the count from CSV in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to Python. I have a csv file with 3 columns (BCID, Column1, Column2). Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YHNqUzkImLqI12T-XRhilanu1mZYfPiV) to that csv and a snapshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HakP.png)

The both columns contain 6 strings (C, CD, D, N, S, SN). I want to track how these strings are changed within these two columns and create a matrix of these strings like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GzRL.png)

The texts inside these matrix (e.g., C_C, C_D, S_N etc.) will be replaced by counting the number of rows which fulfills the corresponding condition. For example Row 'C' and Column 'C' will represent number of entries where both columns contains 'C' and 'C'. Consecutively Row 'C' and Column 'D' will represent counts where Column1 contains 'C' and Column2 contains 'D' and so on.

I don't think creating 36 variables with 36 conditions and checking them for each rows using loop with the csv is a good idea. I tried to go with Pandas Dataframe but couldn't figure out how to create a dataframe with both row and columns as strings. How can I do that? If it can be done, how to calculate the value counts in that case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an exciting project. What have you done so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not start any coding because I only thought about creating 36 variables to store 36 conditional outputs and count them. It was obvious to be not a smart move. But, answer from @ScottBoston worked very fine and its interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Column2  C  CD  D  N  S
Column1                
C        7   3  3  2  0
CD       2   7  0  2  3
D        3   1  5  0  1
N        1   1  2  3  0
S        1   1  0  1  5
SN       0   1  0  0  1
```

Missing values in 'Column2' to get full 6x6 then use:

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(df.Column1.unique(),axis=1,fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Column2  CD  C  D  S  N  SN
Column1                    
C         3  7  3  0  2   0
CD        7  2  0  3  2   0
D         1  3  5  1  0   0
N         1  1  2  0  3   0
S         1  1  0  5  1   0
SN        1  0  0  1  0   0
```

#### Option 2 use pd.crosstab

```
pd.crosstab(df.Column1, df.Column2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the final output, the Column2 is found as 'CD', 'C', 'D', 'S', 'N', 'SN'. If I want to get that as the same order of Column1 (i.e., 'C', 'CD', 'D', 'N', 'S', 'SN'), what should be done within reindex? Thanks again @Scott in advance.

Comment: You can use `reindex` operation to achiece this. df_out = df.group..... df_out.reindex(df_out.index).